# python program to accept a string from the command line and print all files matching that string within a folder

Tags: python, command-line, filesystems

How do i write a program to accept a string from the command line and print all filenames matching that string within a folder(also subfolders)?

I'm looking for a pattern match.

Comment: File names, or contents within the files?

Comment: `import sys; import glob; print('\\n'.join(glob.glob(sys.argv[1])))`.

Comment: Exact match, partial match, pattern match? Include subfolders? Wildcards?

Comment: @filmor, the code shows me an indexError:list out of range error when I run it in the command line.

Comment: @Junuxx yeah, I mentioned subfolders too. I want a pattern match.

Comment: @user2115365, that code-snippet was more or less a hint for you that you didn't provide enough information to get a sensible answer. You'd have to launch it as `python -c "<snippet>" <pattern>`. And you question /still/ doesn't mention subfolders or the kind of pattern you want to use.

Comment: @filmor i modified the description. Does it make it clear for a fuller answer? If I type "question" as the string in the command line and the folder contains "question1.c", "question2.py"...those files should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import sys, os, operator, re
    def filesMatching(pattern, top):
        return [f for f in os.listdir(top) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(top,f)) and re.match(pattern, f)] + reduce (operator.__concat__, [filesMatching (pattern, os.path.join(top,f)) for f in os.listdir (top) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(top,f))], [])

    print (filesMatching (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

Comment: Less efficient, but in one line

Comment: python <name>.py "pattern" "dir" ?

Comment: yeah. There is no need for quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use this technique

```
import os, fnmatch, sys
def all_files(root, patterns='*', single_level=False, yield_folders=False):
    # Expand patterns from semicolon-separated string to list
    patterns = patterns.split(';')
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        if yield_folders:
            files.extend(subdirs)
        files.sort( )
        for name in files:
            for pattern in patterns:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                    yield os.path.join(path, name)
                    break
        if single_level:
            break

user_definedpath, filepattern = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
# Invoking the all_files and putting them into list
#thefiles = list(all_files('/tmp', '*.py;*.htm;*.html'))
thefiles = list(all_files(user_definedpath, filepattern))
print thefiles
```

Now you can save this file as `sample.py` in say `/tmp/abc/sample.py`
Then you can execute as `python /tmp/abc/sample.py "/tmp/xyz/" "*.py;*.txt"`

Comment: But i wanted to be able to match a string that I give to the filename in the folder.
Like if i give 'questi' as the string and the folder(and the subfolders) contain 'question1.c','question2.c',questions.doc' it should return those names

Comment: You can give filename instead of *.py

Comment: I do something like python sample.py "Users/sample" "welcome.txt"
In this case Users/sample contains welcome.txt but it doesnt show up.
the answer is [].

Comment: You should give proper and fullpath. In my windows machine It is Working.